# Should I use "my workplace" or other words when I'm talking about commuting?

Tags: word-choice

The sentence is: My **workplace** is not far away from my home.

should I use :

**"workplace?"**

**work?**

**office?** (actually, I don't have an office or a desk. I'm a worker(an electrician), my job is to repair something in a building, so I think "office" is not proper)

**other words?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence :

```
 My workplace is not far away from my home
```

is correct as workplace or place of work refers to where you go and work ,It has nothing to do whether it is fixed or changing .
You can refer this [link](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/workplace/synonyms/) for more synonyms of same.For those cases where there is a probability that it can be far from home use something like this:-

```
   My workplace is not always far away from my home.
```

Here we can consider cases when the location of your work can be far